# ScrollView automatically scroll to focus child component QML

Tags: qt, qml

This is a follow up of another question i had, that can be find on this post

[When tab to another component position the correspondent scroll in QML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53634108/when-tab-to-another-component-position-the-correspondent-scroll-in-qml)

What i want to do is, as i tab on different components i want the scroll to automatically scroll to that same component so that the following happens:

lets suppose im here

[image]

now i do 2 tabs and i go to

[image]

here it should adjust the scroll to show at least that `TextField` complete.
Like this

[image]

The problem here is that i'm using `QtQuick.Controls 1.4` for load of component `ScrollView`
so with that example i get the error:
`Error: Cannot assign to non-existent property "contentY"`
with `import QtQuick.Controls 2.2`it works well.

I provide now a minimalistic code to show the same as the images:

```
import QtQuick 2.9
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4
import QtQuick.Controls 2.0
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.3
import QtQuick.Controls.Styles 1.4

ApplicationWindow {
    id: window
    title: "Stack"
    visible: true
    height: 200
    width: 400
    ListModel {
        id: libraryModel
        ListElement {
            text: "A Masterpiece"
        }
        ListElement {
            text: "Brilliance"
        }
        ListElement {
            text: "Outstanding"
        }
    }

    Item {
        id: page
        anchors.fill: parent
        width:parent.width
        height: parent.height
        ScrollView {
            id:scrollView
            anchors.fill:parent
            style: ScrollViewStyle{
                handle: Rectangle {
                    implicitWidth: 30
                    color:  "black"
                }
                scrollToClickedPosition: true
                transientScrollBars:true
            }
            function scrollToY(y) {
                scrollView.contentItem.contentY = y;
            }
            Column{
                width:parent.width
                spacing:10
                TextField {
                    id:textField
                    implicitHeight: 30
                    font.bold: true
                    onFocusChanged: if(focus) { scrollView.scrollToY(y); }
                }
                ComboBox {
                    id:comboBox
                    anchors.topMargin: 10
                    textRole: "text"
                    model: libraryModel
                    onFocusChanged: if(focus) { scrollView.scrollToY(y); }
                }
                TextField {
                    id:textField2
                    anchors.topMargin: 10
                    implicitHeight: 30
                    font.bold: true
                    onFocusChanged: if(focus) { scrollView.scrollToY(y); }
                }
                ComboBox {
                    id:comboBox2
                    anchors.topMargin: 10
                    textRole: "text"
                    model: libraryModel
                    onFocusChanged: if(focus) { scrollView.scrollToY(y); }
                }
                TextField {
                    id:textField3
                    anchors.topMargin: 10
                    implicitHeight: 30
                    font.bold: true
                    onFocusChanged: if(focus) { scrollView.scrollToY(y); }
                }
                ComboBox {
                    id:comboBox3
                    anchors.topMargin: 10
                    textRole: "text"
                    model: libraryModel
                    onFocusChanged: if(focus) { scrollView.scrollToY(y); }
                }
                TextField {
                    id:textField4
                    anchors.topMargin: 10
                    implicitHeight: 30
                    font.bold: true
                    onFocusChanged: if(focus) { scrollView.scrollToY(y); }
                }
                ComboBox {
                    id:comboBox4
                    anchors.topMargin: 10
                    textRole: "text"
                    model: libraryModel
                    onFocusChanged: if(focus) { scrollView.scrollToY(y); }
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I edited my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/53650089/6165833

For `QtQuick.Controls 1.4` the `ScrollView` behaves in a different way and you access the `Flickable` through `ScrollView.flickableItem` (which is now read-only for `QtQuick.Controls 2.2`).

So you can still do the trick by using `flickableItem` instead of `contentItem`.

You add this function into your ScrollView (with id: scrollView)

```
// For QtQuick.Controls 1.4
function scrollToY(y) {
    scrollView.flickableItem.contentY = y;
}
```

And then you need to call that in every item when they get the focus :

```
TextField {
    id:textField3
    anchors.topMargin: 10
    implicitHeight: 30
    font.bold: true
    onFocusChanged: if(focus) { scrollView.scrollToY(y); }
}
```

Comment: I was almost there, but you got faster. Thanks :P